# Loop 1st element of 2d List

Tags: arrays, perl, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list like this

```
[[hash,hash,hash],useless,useless,useless]
```

I want to take the first element of hashes and loop through it - i try this:

```
my @list = get_list_somehow();
print Dumper($list[0][0]); print Dumper($list[0][1]);print Dumper($list[0][2]);
```

and i am able to access the elements fine manually, but when i try this

```
my @list = get_list_somehow()[0];
print Dumper($list[0]); print Dumper($list[1]);print Dumper($list[2]);
foreach(@list){
         do_something_with($_);
}
```

only `$list[0]` returns a value (the first hash, everything else is undefined)

Comment: Can you show your actual data instead of placeholders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking a subscript `[0]` of the return value of `get_list_somehow()` (although technically, you need parentheses there). What you *need* to do is to dereference the first element in that list. So:

```
my @list = get_list_somehow();
my $first = $list[0];              # take first element
my @newlist = @$first;             # dereference array ref
```

Of course, this is cumbersome and verbose, and if you just want to print the array with `Data::Dumper` you can just do:

```
print Dumper $list[0];
```

Or if you just want the first array, you can do it in one step. Although this looks complicated and messy:

```
my @list = @{ (get_list_somehow())[0] };
```

The `@{ ... }` will expand an array reference inside it, which is what hopefully is returned from your subscript of the list from `get_list_somehow()`.

Comment: thanks: I used this one - my @list = @{ (get_list_somehow())[0] };
works

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking that your sample data looks like this:

```
my @data = [
               {
                   one   => 1,
                   two   => 2,
                   three => 3,
               },
               "value",
               "value",
               "value",
           ];
```

That is, the first element of `@data`, `$data[0]` *is* your hash. Is that correct?

Your hash is a *hash reference*. That is the `$data[0]` *points* to the memory location where that hash is stored.

To get the hash itself, it must be *dereferenced*:

```
my %hash = %{ $data[0] };   # Dereference the hash in $data[0]
for my $key ( keys %hash ) {
    say qq( \$hash{$key} = "$hash{$key}".);
}
```

I could have done the dereferencing in one step...

```
for my $key ( keys @{ $data[0] } ) {
    say qq(\$data[0]->{$key} = ") . $data[0]->{$key} . qq(".);
}
```

Take a look at the [Perl Reference Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for information on how to work with references.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a bit on your data structure here:

```
my $list = [
  [ { a => 1,
      b => 2,
      c => 3, },
    { d => 4, }
    { e => 5, }
  ], undef, undef, undef,
];
```

Then we get the 0th (first) element of the top-level array reference, which is another array reference, and then the 0th (first) element of THAT array reference, which is the first hash reference:

```
my $hr = $list->[0][0];
```

And iterate over the hash keys. That could also be written as one step: `keys %{ $list->[0][0] }`. It's a bit easier to see what's going on when broken out into two steps.

```
for my $key (keys %$hr) {
  printf "%s => %s\n", $key, $hr->{$key};
}
```

Which outputs:

```
c => 3
a => 1
b => 2
```